# Can Windows 7 OS on harddrive use SSD for prefetch (SuperFetch)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, prefetch

I have a Windows 7 computer with a primary drive being conventional 1 TB hard drive. I have installed an additional 128 GB SSD which I use to keep some of my frequently used data and applications.

I have more than 64 GB of the space still free and I thought it might be nice to use it to speed up my booting time, which seems often quite slow, and to reduce the file traffic which happens after booting, when logging in (sometimes it takes several minutes before the hard disk stops working).

By default the Prefetch is located on my hard drive on `C:\Windows\Prefetch`. Would it make sense to move it to the SSD, and how would I do it?

Also, is there any performance to be gained by enabling ReadyBoost on the SSD? (I have 16 GB of RAM).

Answer (score 1):

[Only Windows 8 enables Superfetch for HDDs, but disables it for SSDs](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Disabling-Hibernation-Superfetch-onboard-VGA#time=05m50s) on the fly. So, for Windows 7 you should install Windows and all applications on the SSD to get the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 automatically enables Superfetch *for all HDD's* and automatically disables it *for all SSD's.*

Windows 8 and 10, however, analyze *performance* of the system drive (be it HDD *or* SSD), and chooses to enable or disable superfetch based on the drive's performance. Which means it may sometimes make the wrong choice.

In my case, Windows 10 enabled superfetch for my laptop's SSD. For one reason or another my SSD scores very low at Windows analysis test, but it *does* work pretty fast in practice — all my programs open up (almost) instantly. After I switched superfetch off, I didn't notice any increased lag.

*Imho, it's best to turn off Superfetch for all decent SSD drives, no matter the Windows performance score.*